# jQuery Send HTML receive JSON

Tags: jquery

When using jquery with php, is it possible to send data as HTML but receive data back as json? In my case i'm sending form data as HTML since json can only handle alphanumeric data. If the form contained error, an array of error messages is returned, which I'll append to error message divs, if not, the user is redirected. Is it possible to do this? What datatype should I specify and should I return the array using json_encode

```
$("#sform").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(#sform).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        //What data type to sepcify here? Data goes as HTML but returns as json
        url: "user_verify.php",
        success: function(data) {
            //Print the php arrays data here to errormessage divs
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `"since json can only handle alphanumeric data."` Nope, it can handle Unicode.

Comment: missing double quotes in `$(#sform)` in your data part.. Also you can set `dataType:'json'` if you are returning `json` from `php`

Comment: You're not actually sending your data as HTML (`.serialize()` doesn't create html), but in any case the response type doesn't have to be the same: the `dataType` option tells jQuery what format to expect the response in, so use `dataType:"json"` and code your PHP accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell the server what type of data you're expecting back, use the `dataType` argument:

```
$("#sform").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(#sform).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "user_verify.php",
        success: function(data) {
            //Print the php arrays data here to errormessage divs
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you don't specify `dataType` then `$.ajax` will try to guess the type based on the header sent back from the server.

In your case, you can also add this to your php page:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and as you stated, return your data with `json_encode()`.

If you don't to `POST` data, you can also check out the `getJSON()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

note: using `dataType` AND setting the `content-type` to `application/json` may be redundant, but it can add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType : 'json'` If you are returning `json` from `php`

```
$("#sform").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        //What data type to sepcify here? Data goes as HTML but returns as json
        url: "user_verify.php",
        success: function(data) {
            //Print the php arrays data here to errormessage divs
        },
        dataType:'json'
    });
    return false;
});
```

PS : In your question `i'm sending form data as HTML` but you are using `.serialize()` API, which means you are sending your data encode in string. So you are not sending any HTML